# TextTemplating target in a .Net Core project

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-core, t4

I have recently migrated a test project to .NET Core 2.0. That test project used text templates to generate some repetitive code. The previous project had a build target to generate all T4-templates before build. Therefore, the generated code is also not checked in into the VCS.

I had used this snippet in the project to ensure that templates are built:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <!-- Default VisualStudioVersion to 15 (VS2017) -->
  <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">15.0</VisualStudioVersion>
  <!-- Determinate VSToolsPath -->
  <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  <!-- Run T4 generation if there are outdated files -->
  <TransformOnBuild>True</TransformOnBuild>
  <TransformOutOfDateOnly>True</TransformOutOfDateOnly>
</PropertyGroup>
<!-- Import TextTemplating target -->
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" />
```

My first approach was to keep this fragment and copy it to the new .NET Core project file.

Inside Visual Studio, this works because apparently, `VSToolsPath` is set correctly. However, when I run the .NET Core SDK tools, as for example `dotnet test` (as I do on the build server), `VSToolsPath` maps to `Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.3` and there, the text templating targets cannot be found.

Because that did not work, I also tried to simply install the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating` package from Nuget but that has two problems:

1. it does not officially support .NET Core and installs for .NET 4.6.1 and
2. Nuget does not seem to install anything, so I cannot adjust the paths in the project file.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 6):

To support building T4 templates while building `dotnet build` you need to use `Custom Text Template Host`, which already exists for .NET Core (https://github.com/atifaziz/t5). To include it, add to your project in any `ItemGroup` this element:
`<DotNetCliToolReference Include="T5.TextTransform.Tool" Version="1.1.0-*" />`.
As Visual Studio already has it's own `Text Template Host` implementation, your added element should be conditioned only for .NET Core. For example:

```xml
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(MSBuildRuntimeType)'=='Core'">
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="T5.TextTransform.Tool" Version="1.1.0-*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And at the same time you should condition out of .NET Core your settings for Visual Studio's Text Template Host, like this: `Condition="'$(MSBuildRuntimeType)'=='Full'"`.

You should also add `<Import Project="Sdk.targets" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" Condition="'$(MSBuildRuntimeType)'=='Full'" />` before importing `Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets` to make everything work correctly with .NET Core `csproj` in Visual Studio.

If you need to be able to clean up all generated code, you should rename your templates from `*.tt` to `*.Generated.tt`, all the code will be generated under `*.Generated.cs` and it will be possible to filter these file out at `dotnet clean` action.

The complete example of what it will look like in your `csproj`:

```xml
<!-- T4 build support for .NET Core (Begin) -->

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(MSBuildRuntimeType)'=='Core'">
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="T5.TextTransform.Tool" Version="1.1.0-*" />
  <TextTemplate Include="**\*.Generated.tt" />
  <Generated Include="**\*.Generated.cs" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="TextTemplateTransform" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(MSBuildRuntimeType)'=='Core'">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="**\*.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" Command="dotnet tt %(TextTemplate.Identity)" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="**\*.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>

<Target Name="TextTemplateClean" AfterTargets="Clean">
  <Delete Files="@(Generated)" />
</Target>

<!-- T4 build support for .NET Core (End) -->


<!-- T4 build support for Visual Studio (Begin) -->

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(MSBuildRuntimeType)'=='Full'">
  <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  <!-- This is what will cause the templates to be transformed when the project is built (default is false) -->
  <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
  <!-- Set to true to force overwriting of read-only output files, e.g. if they're not checked out (default is false) -->
  <OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>true</OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>
  <!-- Set to false to transform files even if the output appears to be up-to-date (default is true)  -->
  <TransformOutOfDateOnly>false</TransformOutOfDateOnly>
</PropertyGroup>

<Import Project="Sdk.targets" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" Condition="'$(MSBuildRuntimeType)'=='Full'" />
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" Condition="'$(MSBuildRuntimeType)'=='Full'" />

<!-- T4 build support for Visual Studio (End) -->
```

If you don't want to rename your template files and you don't need to clean up them, then replace:

```xml
  <TextTemplate Include="**\*.Generated.tt" />
  <Generated Include="**\*.Generated.cs" />
```

with:

```xml
  <TextTemplate Include="**\*.tt" />
```

And delete:

```xml
<Target Name="TextTemplateClean" AfterTargets="Clean">
  <Delete Files="@(Generated)" />
</Target>
```

For more information see:

How to set up code generation on `dotnet build`:
https://notquitepure.info/2018/12/12/T4-Templates-at-Build-Time-With-Dotnet-Core/

How to set up code generation on build for Visual Studio and .NET Core `csproj`:
https://thomaslevesque.com/2017/11/13/transform-t4-templates-as-part-of-the-build-and-pass-variables-from-the-project/

The full example of the generation of multiple files from a single T4 template:
https://github.com/Konard/T4GenericsExample

**Update:**

[GitHub.com/Mono/T4](https://github.com/Mono/T4) [is even better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57741346/710069).

Answer (score 1):

You are at the mercy of someone writing a port for dotnet core.

This is old: http://www.bricelam.net/2015/03/12/t4-on-aspnet5.html

Or use a different templating tool entirely, though of course I understand if that’s not an option.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [Konard's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56144157/1901857) of "Update: https://github.com/mono/t4 is even better."

#### Install Mono/T4 (dotnet-t4) as a tool

- If you are running an Azure devops pipeline, you can add it as a step - see the first part of https://stackoverflow.com/a/60667867/1901857.
- If you are building in a linux dockerfile, add this before you build (we were using .net 6 on alpine, but it should be fine with other distros and versions):

```
# you will see a warning if this folder is not on PATH
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.dotnet/tools"
RUN dotnet tool install -g dotnet-t4
```

- If you want to use the tool on your dev machine, instead of VS TextTemplating, run a one-off install from powershell (but every dev in your team will need to do this):

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-t4
```

#### Run t4 on build - dev machine and pipeline

dotnet-t4 is setup very similarly to t5 in [Konard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56144157/1901857)

**Option 1 - dotnet-t4 installed on your dev machine**

Add this to your csproj file. No conditional settings required.

```xml
  <!-- T4 build support for .NET Core (Begin) -->

  <ItemGroup>
    <TextTemplate Include="**\*.tt" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="TextTemplateTransform" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Remove="**\*.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" Command="t4 %(TextTemplate.Identity)" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Include="**\*.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <!-- T4 build support for .NET Core (End) -->
```

**Option 2 - use VS templating on your dev machine**

If you don't want everyone to install the tool locally, you can still add conditional build steps to the project, as per Konard's answer. Note that Visual Studio is now 64-bit, so you can use `MSBuildExtensionsPath` instead of `MSBuildExtensionsPath32`:

```xml
  <!-- T4 build support for .NET Core (Begin) -->

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(MSBuildRuntimeType)'=='Core'">
    <TextTemplate Include="**\*.tt" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="TextTemplateTransform" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(MSBuildRuntimeType)'=='Core'">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Remove="**\*.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" Command="t4 %(TextTemplate.Identity)" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Include="**\*.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <!-- T4 build support for .NET Core (End) -->

  <!-- T4 build support for Visual Studio (Begin) -->

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(MSBuildRuntimeType)'=='Full'">
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
    <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
    <!--Other properties can be inserted here--> 
    <!--Set to true to force overwriting of read-only output files, e.g. if they're not checked out (default is false)--> 
    <OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>true</OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>
    <!--Set to false to transform files even if the output appears to be up-to-date (default is true)-->  
    <TransformOutOfDateOnly>false</TransformOutOfDateOnly>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" Condition="'$(MSBuildRuntimeType)'=='Full'" />

  <!-- T4 build support for Visual Studio (End) -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just use [T4Executer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TimMaes.ttexecuter). You can set which templates to execute before build, after build or ignore specific templates. Works good with VS2017-19

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with `msbuild` today but [not yet `dotnet build`](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/9677).

Documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-in-a-build-process?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp#edit-the-project-file).