# Use TextTransform (tt files) into the Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-devops

Is it possible to transform the **/*.tt file into a *.cs file. 
Using Azure Devops pipeline?

Otherwise is there a CLI command available for Dotnet core using TextTransform ?

I already test : [T5.TextTransform.Tool](https://www.nuget.org/packages/T5.TextTransform.Tool/) but is don't work (and deprecated)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How i solve this problem using Devops pipeline + script:

1. As mention @Leo Liu-MSFT Install dotnet-t4

install global **-g**

[image]

2. Create powershell script and find tt file

Seach all *.tt file and convert them with the **t4** command

[image]

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Filter *.tt -Recurse -File -Name| ForEach-Object {
    $file = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($_);
    $directory = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($_)
    "Conversion file : " + $file
    t4 "$directory\$file" -I="$directory"
}
```

NOTE : It is important to place the T4.ps1 file in the parent directory of your *.tt files

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to transform the **/*.tt file into a *.cs file. Using Azure Devops pipeline?

The answer is yes.

According to the state of the package [T5.TextTransform.Tool](https://www.nuget.org/packages/T5.TextTransform.Tool/):

> T5 was a stopgap measure for a time when Mono.TextTemplating was not
>   available for .NET Core. Now that that is no longer the case, T5 is
>   not needed and no longer being maintained. **Use Mono.TextTemplating's
>   dotnet-t4 instead**.

[image]

So, we could use the [Mono.TextTemplating](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.TextTemplating/) instead of `T5.TextTransform.Tool`.

Besides, there is also an implementation of the `TextTransform.exe` command-line tool, we could use the command line to transform the `.tt` file into `.cs` file:

```
"%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\TextTemplating\1.2\texttransform.exe" -out %1.cs -P %2 -P "%ProgramFiles%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5" %1.tt
```

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646580/get-visual-studio-to-run-a-t4-template-on-every-build/3041089) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes i solved it, thank you for your post it's helped me. 
I will post new answer with all my step to fix it

Comment: Do you guys know if this approach would work in a .NET Core 5.0 project? When I try to install the "dotnet-t4" NuGet package in my project, I am getting this error: NU1202: Package dotnet-t4 2.2.1 is not compatible with net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0). Package dotnet-t4 2.2.1 supports: netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1) / any