# T4 templates in F# project

Tags: visual-studio, f#, t4

I have been using T4 templates in C# projects in Visual Studio. Now I am trying to get some generation in an F# project, using [mono t4](https://github.com/mono/t4).

I have attempted to adapt the examples I found (for example [TextTemplating target in a .Net Core project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47691299/texttemplating-target-in-a-net-core-project)), but I have not been successful, as in "Nothing is generated".

This is the project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>net4.8</TargetFramework>
      <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Template.tt" />
    <Compile Include="**.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Mono.TextTemplating" Version="2.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Update="FSharp.Core" Version="7.0.200" />
  </ItemGroup>  

</Project>
```

It should be possible (I hope), to add some entries manually in the .fsproj file to force msbuild to run the transformation of the .tt file (in C# it all occurs automatically), however I don't know:

- Whether it is possible.
- How to do it.

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <!-- ... other configuration ... -->

  <Target Name="TransformTemplates" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="t4 -o $(IntermediateOutputPath)\GeneratedFile.cs Template.tt" />
  </Target>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)\GeneratedFile.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

TransformTemplates is a custom target that runs before the build

The Exec task runs the t4 command to transform Template.tt into a C# file.

The generated C# file should included in the compilation.